# Travel between Schengen and Non-Schengen Country

Tags: visas, schengen, netherlands, ukraine, hungary

I will be traveling to The Netherlands, Hungary and Ukraine on business. According to my itinerary, I will be first staying 6 days in The Netherlands, flying to Hungary for two days, entering Ukraine by car from Hungary (spending 3 days there)and returning to Hungary by car from where I will fly back to my home country.

I have to apply separately for the Ukrainian visa, but I am first applying for the Schengen Visa. Not considering my trip to Ukraine, I will be spending a longer time in Hungary (9 days). My confusion revolves around two questions:

1. Should I still apply for visa at The Netherlands Consulate showing them my travel reservations to Ukraine from Hungary or should I apply at the Hungarian Consulate?
2. Also, on a side note, if I was just traveling to The Netherlands first (6 days stay) and Hungary (9 days stay) and I applied for visa at the Dutch Consulate, would they deny my application and ask me to apply at the Hungarian Consulate?

Answer (score 4):

The first rule for Schengen visa is your main stay, which usually is the longer one, but can also be the one with the more important meetings.

So, even with the days as you mention, it may be that the stay in the Netherlands is way more important to you and that you are right in applying at the Dutch embassy.

Please, do remember that you will leave and re-enter the Schengen zone and as such need a multiple entry visa.

The only way around that would be not returning to Hungary, if that is possible.